# How to Iterate Over Array and Stringify a Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to accumulate a property of an array and write save it back to the array as a string to later be parsed with `JSON.parse`.

In the initial data set the `items` property is an array.

I would like to restructure the data such that items is a string of the objects.

Given something like:

```
[{
   {
     "n":"1",
     "items": [0: "{"id":"id1","desc":"description1"}",
               1: "{"id":"id2","desc":"description2"}"
               2: "{"id":"id3","desc":"description3"}"]
   },
   {
     "n":"2",
     "items": [0: "{"id":"id4","desc":"description4"}",
               1: "{"id":"id5","desc":"description5"}"
               2: "{"id":"id6","desc":"description6"}"]
   }
}]
```

Convert to:

```
[{
   {
     "n":"1",
     "items": "[{"id":"id1","desc":"description1"}","{"id":"id2","desc":"description2"}","{"id":"id3","desc":"description3"}]"
   },
   {
     "n":"2",
     "items": "[{"id":"id4","desc":"description4"}","{"id":"id5","desc":"description5"}", "{"id":"id6","desc":"description6"}]"
   }
}]
```

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had to clean up your data, so I will go with the assumption that the data structure I set below is what you actually meant.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "n":"1",
    "items": [
      {"id":"id1","desc":"description1"},
      {"id":"id2","desc":"description2"},
      {"id":"id3","desc":"description3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "n":"2",
    "items": [
      {"id":"id4","desc":"description4"},
      {"id":"id5","desc":"description5"},
      {"id":"id6","desc":"description6"}
    ]
  }
];

const newData = data.map(val => {
  return Object.assign({}, val, {
    items: JSON.stringify(val.items)
  });
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  arr.map(({ items, ...rest }) => ({ items: JSON.stringify(items), ...rest }));
```

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it than mine. I never use the `...rest` functionality or object destructuring, so I always forget the use-cases of it.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.